# Помогите проверить программу на java и исправить ошибки

Tags: java, массивы

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int N, first;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    System.out.println("enter number");
    first = in.nextInt();
    N = in.nextInt();
    if (N != first)
        count++;
    System.out.println(count);
```

Нужно было написать программу, которая не выводит первое число, которое написали.

Пример
*ввод:*
3 4 5 6 3

*вывод:*
4 5 6

Comment: Вам не нужен первый цикл. Да и массив вроде ни к чему - получили число, проверили, вывели

Comment: а извините просто впервые тут

Comment: @MBo так нужно было написать? но у меня все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: *"у меня все равно выдает ошибку"* - ¿Предлагаете читателям вопроса ее угадать?

Comment: Ошибка скорее всего связана с тем, что в цикле вы сравниваете переменную цикла `i` с некой переменной `N`, которая НЕ проинициализирована, и которую вы _зачем-то меняете_ внутри цикла:  `N = in.nextInt();`  Также внутри цикла _зачем-то на каждой итерации_ переприсваивается значение `first`.  Непонятно, зачем заведена переменная `count`, и для чего выводится она, а не то, что требуется в задании (введённые числа).  Приведите оригинал условия задачи, так как представленный код относится к ней _весьма отдалённо_.

Comment: @vlua в процессе редактирования ваш [первоначальный код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1572173/1)  c **массивом** превратился во что-то непонятное.

Comment: Нет. Сначала, до цикла, вводите переменную first, а в цикле сравниваете новые введенные числа с ней

Answer (score 0):

Если рассматривать *оригинальный* скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в нём просматриваются следующие проблемы:

- ошибка компиляции: переменная `num` объявлена и инициализируется внутри *первого* цикла несколько раз, а обращение к ней выполняется внутри *второго* цикла, поэтому в первом цикле `num` отмечена серым цветом (неиспользуемая), а во втором цикле -- красным (вне зоны определения / видимости).
- связанная логическая ошибка: числа в первом цикле будут считываться *попарно* и массив будет заполняться некорректно; для завершения цикла во входном потоке должно быть не 5 чисел, а 8, иначе цикл "зависнет" в ожидании ввода.
  Просто следовало определить переменную `num` *перед* первым циклом и прочитать первое входное значение *один раз*.
- ещё одна логическая ошибка во втором цикле, итерация со *второго* элемента `(for int i = 1; ...)`

C учётом исправлений указанных моментов решение задачи может выглядеть как показано ниже, с предположением, что *сначала* вводится требуемое число, а после него массив ровно из 4 элементов.  Также предположим, что *действительно необходимо* сохранить входные значения внутри массива:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers");

int first = in.nextInt();

// всё же заведём массив, чтобы разнести ввод и вывод 
int[] arr = new int[4];

// ввод
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = in.nextInt();
}

// отфильтрованный вывод с использованием улучшенного цикла for (for-each)
for (int n : arr) {
    if (n != first) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Enter 5 numbers
3 4 5 6 3
4
5
6
```